# selecting partially matching data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I was wondering if there was a way to select partially matching data in SQL.
 For example, if I had:

```
name 
----
Index
Index.jpg 
Index.html
Foot
foot.jpg
Hand
head.jpg
```

And wanted to show(all names with matching strings):

```
name
----
Index
Index.jpg 
Index.html
Foot
foot.jpg
```

Could I use a regex match for this?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the logic for the selection?  I would just use `where name < 'hand'`, which would work assuming the collation is case insensitive.

Comment: I would like to select and return all of the data that matches. I am building a report that finds all of the asset information that has associated files with it(so Index and Index.jpg). So if an asset did not have any matching information(like Hand and head.jpg) it wouldn't show up.

Comment: Do you mean you're looking for `File.*` matches?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this example I made in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16a86/6/0).

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT name AS 'Asset' FROM Table1 WHERE name NOT LIKE '%.%'
) AS A 
JOIN 
(
SELECT name AS 'Files' FROM Table1 WHERE name LIKE '%.%'
) AS B 
ON A.Asset = SUBSTRING(B.Files, 1, INSTR(B.Files, '.') - 1)
```